# Хостинг запоминает старую версию файла

Tags: файлы, хостинг

У меня проблема, хостинг запоминает старую версию файла, и не видет новую. Что делать?

Comment: написать в хостинг, что бы не занимался тем, чем должен заниматься nginx/apache. Скорее всего, файл отдается по http/get и настроено большое время кеширования.

Comment: Большинство проблем с хостингом решаются обращением в тех.поддержку хостинга, тем более не называя хостинга, сложно догадаться что же могло прийти в голову разработчикам хостинга. Как сказал @KoVadim Вам также следует посмотреть кеш

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось, действительно это была проблема с кэшэм браузера, я просто добавил название файла GET запрос с time():

```
<img src="filename.webp?hsh=<?php echo time(); ?>">
```